# Add an element in an existing HashMap

Tags: java, json, algorithm, parsing, hashmap

The folowing code takes elements with assistance of a json parser. My problem is, when i find a **same value** then i want to put an **new element** (eg "title2") in the **existing hashmap** with the same value!
My first thought is to make an new loop (for...) after the first loop and to do some actions here but it's hard. I can not find an efficient way.
Is there a solution for this? Any idea?

```
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);
try {
    //Get the elements
    HashMap<Integer, String> mapCompare = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
    //Loop the array
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> mapInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);
        mapInfo.put("id", e.getString("id"));
        mapInfo.put("title", e.getString("title"));
        mapInfo.put("value", e.getString("value"));
        if (mapCompare.containsValue(e.getString("value")) {
            mapInfo.put("isSame?", "yes");
        } else {
            mapInfo.put("isSame?", "no");
        }
        mapCompare.put(i, e.getString("value"));
        listInfo.add(mapInfo);
    }
  // a new for ??? and how ??? 
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
return listInfo;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is designed to be efficient for *key* lookups, not *value* lookups.

It sounds like you might want a bidirectional map - have a look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [`BiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) interface and probably the [`HashBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) implementation.

Alternatively, you could use a [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) where each key can map to multiple values - so you'd have a single entry for `value` which would contain all of the values you've added for that key.

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but I'd expect *one* of those approaches to work for you.

Comment: Consider that there are 10 json arrays. Each array has a value and a title. I take these arrays with a parser. So, for each array i make a hashmap with two keys, "value" and "title".
Then consider that 2 of 10 json arrays has the same value(eg X) but different title. So i want a hashmap with value "X" and with two titles therefore a new key "title2". For this example the final result is 9 hashmap. 

I hope that you understand my problem! :)
Anyway i see that your answer maybe help me! These maps have many functions.